# SQL query for counting the number of categories

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE prodinfo ( prodtype string, prodname string );
```

Some of the values:

```
book    | alice in wonderland
shoe    | bata
book    | c++ primer
cutlery | spoon
book    | SCWCD
cutlery | knife
```

I need to find the number of products in each category.

```
book    | 3
shoe    | 1
cutlery | 2
```

How to write an SQL query for this?

P.S: This is not a homework assignment. I am working on something and I am stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT prodtype, COUNT(1)
FROM prodinfo
GROUP BY prodType
```

Answer (score 2):

USE GROUP BY and COUNT:

```
SELECT prodtype, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM prodinfo
GROUP BY prodtype
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the "Group By" aggregate to do this.

So your query is

```
Select Count(*) from ProdInfo
Group By ProdType
```

This will return the count of each of the elements.

Note you can use other aggregates, such as Sum() and Average() using this technique.